# Bug overwritePermissions

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

```
message.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.username}`).then
            (channel => channel.overwritePermissions(Support, {
                            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
                            READ_MESSAGES: true
                        }));
                    channel.overwritePermissions(everyone, {
                            SEND_MESSAGES: false,
                            READ_MESSAGES: false
                        });
                    channel.overwritePermissions(message.author, {
                            SEND_MESSAGES: true,
                            READ_MESSAGES: true
                    }); {

                      }
```

I don't know how to add permissions when I create the channel, could someone help me please?

Answer (score 0):

The first errors is that you are using `Support`, `everyone` and `message.author`, those all need to be IDs referring to role ids or member ids

This isn't part of the error but since you asked: if you look at the docs for `<GuildChannelManager>.create()` you can see the second parameter is the options which you can specify `permissionOverwrites`, so you can do this instead of modifying the overwrites in `.then`

https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildChannelManager?scrollTo=create

```js
msg.guild.channels.create(`ticket-${message.author.username}`, {
  type: 'text',
  permissionOverwrites: [
     {
       id: "SUPPORT_ROLE_ID",
       allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGES'],
    },
    {
       id: message.author.id,
       allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGES'],
    },
    {
       id: message.guild.roles.everyone.id,
       allow: ['SEND_MESSAGES', 'READ_MESSAGES'],
    }
  ],
});
```